# How to display Woocommerce category description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the regular wordpress code to display category description:

```
<?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>
```

But how can i display Woocommerce category description?
@@
After one of the comment suggestion i added:

```
                    <?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
global $post, $product; $categ = $product->get_categories(); $term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' ); echo $term->description; 
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Still, not work.

Comment: Woo docs show that the taxonomy is "product_cat"... 
Does this work? : <?php global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();
$term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' );
echo $term->description; ?>

Comment: @Matt.C nop. i found it too on Google, but its not work. thanks anyway !

Comment: could you post a little more of your code, are you using this inside a loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

$count = count($terms); 
if ($count > 0) {

   foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->description;
   }
}
```

Edit for Last answer:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args  = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', $args);

$count = count($terms);
if ($count > 0) {

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<div style="direction:rtl;">';
        echo $term->description;
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: works !! thank you. just the problem now - its display all the categories descriptions, in any category. how can i display only the current category description?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms check here you have got arguments to pass to refine your result

Comment: To ask: can't the lines in which you retrieve the terms be contracted in a single line, this way: `$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');`? You would still get an array of `WP_Term`s objects, so the foreach would still work the very same way :)

Answer (score 5):

[`the_archive_description()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_description/) worked for my purposes when other (more complicated) solutions would not.

Optional before and after string parameters can be added if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can display the product **category description** -

use this code -

```
<?php global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();
$term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' );
echo $term->description; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main answer for some reason displayed more than one description for me.

The answer below solved this for anyone with the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19266706/2703913

Comment: copying the answer from there to here would be useful, saves people a click and re-reading the question